# JQuery FlipTimer Start/Stop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all the timer works on double click, but I want it to work on single click. Secondly, the stop button doesn't work.

**JS:**

```
var clock;      
$(document).ready(function() {          
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
        clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
        autoStart: false    
    });        
    $('#start').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clock.start();
        $(this).attr('id', 'stop');
        $('#stop').html('Stop');
    });
    $('#stop').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clock.stop();
        $(this).attr('id', 'start');
        $('#start').html('Start');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-8 center-block clock" ></div>
<button id="start" class="btn-default center-block">Start</button>
```

Comment: You don't have a stop button...

Comment: Is `FlipClock` a plugin?

Comment: http://flipclockjs.com/

Comment: I don't want to have a stop button, instead I want to change the text and id of the button on click to start/stop.

Comment: you shouldn't have to change the `id` of button in order to fire separate callbacks of starting and stopping. Instead you can use the same button and have a boolean flag letting you know if the clock is ticking or not.

Comment: as for the double-click to start, I suppose we will need to see it in action in order to debug. can you create a fiddle / pen / snippet please?

Comment: Double click to start, it's no more after wrapping the button inside a `div`

Answer (score 0):

If your double-click issue is resolved as per your comment, then the other problem of toggling using the same button can be done like so:

- Have a global `isTicking` variable and set it to `false` initially.
- Inside your click handler for `#start`, you can do something like:

---

```
if (!isTicking){
    isTicking=true;
    clock.start();
    $(this).html('Stop');
}else{
    isTicking=false;
    clock.stop();
    $(this).html('Start');
}
```

Does this help?